# How to change text colour of links in navbar header AND links in nav pills (in shiny app)?

Tags: css, r, shiny, navbar, nav

Here is a redacted version of my shiny app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- tagList(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel(""),
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
      "
        .navbar-default {
            color: red !important;'
        }
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
            color: red !important;
        }
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
            color: pink !important;
        }
        "
    ))),
    
    navbarPage(
      windowTitle = "App Name",
      theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly",
                       base_font = font_google("Lato"),
                       primary = "#333F50",
                       bg = "white",
                       fg = "#D67540"),
      title = "I am the title",
      selected = "Main Tab 1",
      tabPanel(title = "Main Tab 1",
               fluidPage(
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(textInput(inputId = "text_input", label = "Enter text:")),
                   mainPanel(textOutput(outputId = "text_output"))
                 )
               )
               ),
      tabPanel(title = "Main Tab 2",
               fluidPage(
                   fluidRow(
                     column(7,
                            navlistPanel(
                              tabPanel("Tab 1"),
                              tabPanel("Tab 2"),
                              tabPanel("Tab 3"),
                              widths = c(2, 10),
                              well = FALSE)
                            )))
               )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output){
  output$text_output <- renderText(input$text_input)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Currently the text for "Main Tab 1" and "Main Tab 2" is pink and red when hovered/selected.

[image: Main Tab 1]

I would also like to apply a similar change to "Tab 1", "Tab 2" and "Tab 3" - for these I want the text colour to change from teal to black and from white to orange when hovered/selected.

My understanding is that the `!important` next to the `color` value forces all links to inherit the same properties, but I would like different colours for the links in the navbar header and the  links in the nav-pills.

I have asked a related question here:
[How to change text colour of navbarPage links when hovered on (in shiny app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75488188/how-to-change-text-colour-of-navbarpage-links-when-hovered-on-in-shiny-app)

How can I make this change?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Note: Colours are intentionally not aesthetic (just using these for distinction as I'm still learning)

Comment: Just FYI, I've edited my answer to include the `tags$div` code. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I've implemented your request, but see both parts of my answer:

### Part 1 - The Solution

To implement your requested styles, I did two things:

1. I changed your `navListPanel` by inserting it into a `tags$div` with the class name `side_panel`. I housed this `navlistPanel` in a div with a custom class so that the CSS you wanted for the panel didn't bleed into other `.nav` classes, including the main `.nav-header`.

```r
tags$div(
  navlistPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab 1"),
    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
    tabPanel("Tab 3"),
    widths = c(2, 10),
    well = FALSE),
  class = "side_panel"
)
```

2. I then added the following CSS to your `tags$style`, starting each line with `.side_panel` to only affect the class we just created:

```css
.side_panel .nav-pills a:hover {
    color: black; 
    background: rgba(253,126,20, 0.8);
}

.side_panel .nav-pills .nav-link.active {
  color: black;
  background: #fd7e14; /* BS orange */
}
```

Achieving this result
(**Note:** "Tab 2" is being hovered over, the screenshot didn't capture my mouse):

[image]

#### Part 2 - Future Styling

As it seems like you're particular about the style of your app (don't worry, I'm obsessive about this type of styling too), you should consider two things.

1. Rather than inserting all of your CSS at the beginning of your app, consider creating a separate `style.css` file located in a `www` folder. This `www` folder should be in the same directory as your `app.R` file. You can then inject all of this CSS into your app using `shiny::includeCSS("www/style.css")` ([ref link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html#:%7E:text=few%20basic%20rules.-,Other%20methods,-Those%20familiar%20with)).
2. To learn how to stylize custom components of your Shiny apps in the future, you should familiarize yourself with the `Inspect` feature of your browser. I mostly use `bs4Dash` in my apps, so I wasn't as familiar with your app's html components. To find the objects and their CSS, I simply inspected the webpage (right click + inspect) and use `ctrl+shift+c` to click on the tabs and view their CSS. Going one step further, you can change the style of the CSS on the fly by typing in custom values.

Good luck!

Comment: Really comprehensive answer! Thank you :)